# Create directory tree with forward slash in directory name

Tags: perl, subdirectory, creation

Trying to create a directory tree in which one of the directories has a forward slash (/) in the name. See the **$artist** variable for the artist name and my attempts at creating the directory.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Path qw(make_path);
my $srcpath = '/home/<username>;/music';
my $artist = "";
my $album = 'somealbum';

# Using single quotes

#t1
$artist = 'AC/DC';
make_path("${srcpath}/t1/${artist}/${album}/");

#t2
$artist = 'AC//DC';
make_path("${srcpath}/t2/${artist}/${album}/");

#t3
$artist = 'AC\/DC';
make_path("${srcpath}/t3/${artist}/${album}/");

# Using double quotes

#t4
$artist = "AC/DC";
make_path("${srcpath}/t4/${artist}/${album}/");

#t5
$artist = "AC//DC";
make_path("${srcpath}/t5/${artist}/${album}/");

#t6
$artist = "AC\/DC";
make_path("${srcpath}/t6/${artist}/${album}/");

#t7
$artist = "AC\\/DC";
make_path("${srcpath}/t7/${artist}/${album}/");
```

Directory tree I want (5 folders):
/ -> home -> <username> -> music -> AC/DC -> somealbum

Directory tree I get (6 folders):
/ -> home -> <username> -> music -> AC -> DC -> somealbum

Comment: Ever wonder why you see filenames with hyphens representing entities that in real life use slashes?  AC-DC is a legal file or path name.  12-23-2009 is a legal file or path name, whereas 12/23/2009 isn't (unless you really mean the 2009 file in the directory '23', within the directory '12'.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The slash character is an illegal character for a file or directory name.  You will need to substitute some other character, like the dash character.

Comment: Can't believe I needed to be reminded of that.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible, not because of Perl but because the OS filesystem layer forbids it.  There is no escape character that would allow you to embed a `/` (or a `NUL`, for that matter) in a path component.

The usual way this is handled is by an application-specific encoding, such as treating `=n` as `NUL`, `=s` as `/`, and `=e` as `=`.  (I don't know of any applications which actually use that particular encoding; it's just an example.)