# Shell: How to create the directory with slash and parentheses?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, sh

I'd like to create the directory "Dir (A/B)" in "test" folder in one go with the following command:

```
$ mkdir -vp "test/dir (A/B)"
test
test/dir (A
test/dir (A/B)
```

Unfortunately it's creating 'dir (A' in 'test'.

I've tried to escape it, but without success e.g. `mkdir -vp "test/dir (A\/B)"`.

When creating manually in Finder, it works.

How should I escape the arguments? Thanks.

I'm using bash shell.

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to have slashes in directory or file names. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words

Comment: That's right. Since slashes are directory separators, they can't also be a real character in a directory or filename. The kernel doesn't support any kind of escaping.

Comment: The Finder translates `/` to `:` (it won't let you create filenames containing `:`, as this is the directory separator in Mac filesystems).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create directory tree with forward slash in directory name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631499/create-directory-tree-with-forward-slash-in-directory-name)

Comment: @chepner He was hoping that escaping would distinguish them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do:

```
$ mkdir -vp "test/dir (A:B)"
```

The directory will appear as `dir (A/B)` in Finder and file open dialogs, but `dir (A:B)` in shell and other Unix applications.

Note that this is very Mac-specific, it won't work on other flavors of Unix.

Comment: Great trick, thank you. Then I would need to escape my path variable (if dynamic) in a script with something like: path=$(echo $path | sed s#/#:#g)

Comment: Yes, but make sure you only do that to the final component, not the entire path.

Answer (score 2):

Although i would not recommend this, you can create a filename like this:

```
mkdir 'test:dir (A:B)'

# when creating missing folders
mkdir -pv 'test/dir (A:B)'
```

In the finder it will show as: "test/dir (A/B)"

**but** if you look in the bash shell (ls -al), you will see "test:dir (A:B)"